# Is there a way to write the contents of a Word doc to a text area using .NET/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, ms-word, blazor

I have a Razor component with a file input that allows me to save a Word document to a SQL DB as a byte array. I have a separate Razor component with a rich text editor where I can paste a Word document's content into the text area and save that to a DB as a byte array. These components work well individually, but I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to combine the logic of both so that I can upload a Word document, save that to the DB, then get the byte array from the DB and show the contents in the text area.

I found [this demo](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Core-MVC-Display-Word-files-from-Database-in-View.aspx) that gets me part of the way there, but the document's contents appear to be read-only. Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems like the "byte array" would need to be interpreted by Word itself in order to be shown. I mean, assuming it's a random Word document, it could include anything you can do in Word. How is a mere browser supposed to render that content?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by using [Open XML Power Tools](https://github.com/OpenXmlDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools) to first convert the byte array to HTML. Once I have that stored in a string variable, I can set the value of the text area to the variable. I'm using this [Rich Text Editor](https://richtexteditor.com/) to format the contents in the UI.